# What is this branch tracking (if anything) in git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

After creating a branch with --track (or leaving the default, or --notrack), you later wish to be reminded of what a branch is tracking. Is there a way, other than searching through the .git/config file, to display what a branch is tracking?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use: `git branch -vv` to see which branches are tracked and which are not.

Answer (score 9):

Note that with [git1.8.3 (April 22d, 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L43-L45), you have a new way to emphasize the upstream branch:

> "**`git branch -vv`**" learned to paint the name of the branch it integrates with in a different color (**`color.branch.upstream`, which defaults to blue**).

```
C:\prog\git\git>git branch -vv
* master 118f60e [origin/master] Sync with maint
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       |
                       --- now in blue
```

Comment: that part is not colored for for me. I am on mac 1.8.4. Anybody know why?

Comment: @dongshengcn yes, I like setting `git config color.ui always`: https://gist.github.com/VonC/972690#file-gitconfig-L25

Comment: I think that should be `git branch -vv` in the quote box

Comment: what does **vv** stand for?                                                                   https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--vv

Comment: @TimBoland it stands for "extra verbose"

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know for a given branch, you could do:

```
git config --get branch.<branch>.remote
```

If it prints a remote, it's tracking something. If it prints nothing and returns failure, it's not.

Comment: That is nice for getting the repository, but it doesn't get the branch name (which may be different)

Comment: @Casebash: True, but that's a *very* rare situation, and if you know you're in it, you can grab another config variable. This has the benefit (compared to `git branch -vv`) of not having extraneous output (i.e. it's machine-parseable). It will sometimes be useful.

Comment: I'll add for the benefit of other people that the config variable for the branch name is `branch.fees.merge`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access this information in an automated fashion you will want to avoid trying to parse the output of `branch -vv` ([slebetman’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631706/what-is-this-branch-tracking-if-anything-in-git/3631775#3631775)).

Git provides a set of lower-level commands with stable interfaces and output formats. These commands (called “plumbing”) are the preferred interface for ‘scripting’ purposes. The *git for-each-ref* command can provide the required information via the `upstream` token (available in Git 1.6.3 and later):

```
% git for-each-ref --shell --format='

b=%(refname:short) u=%(upstream:short)
# Make a fancy report or do something scripty with the values.
if test -n "$u"; then
  printf "%s merges from %s\n" "$b" "$u" 
else
  printf "%s does not merge from anything\n" "$b" 
fi

' refs/heads/ | sh
master merges from origin/master
other does not merge from anything
pu merges from origin/pu
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the hint [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi)

With the following command you can get the remote tracking branch for a specific branch.

```
git config --get branch.<branch>.merge
```

To change the remote tracking branch you can simply change this config value.

Note: this is an alternative way to `git branch -vv` (already answered here)
and `git branch -u` ([Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch))