# Git: How to list branches with info about tracked remote?

Tags: git, tracking, git-branch

I'd like to have a list of all branches with an info about what do they track. I.e.:

```
$ git branch -a -???
master  <-> origin/master
new_menu  <-> origin/feature1
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/feature1
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get git to show me which branches are tracking what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verbose is what you want:

```
git branch -a -v
```

or

```
git branch -a -vv
```

> --verbose
>
> Show sha1 and commit subject line for each head, along with relationship to upstream branch (if any). If given twice, print the
>   name of the upstream branch, as well.

Comment: -a -v does not list tracking info. -a -vv does.