# show tracked branch

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I get git to show me which branches are tracking what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what)

I've added two remote repos to my Git project

```
$ git remote show
cavneb
origin
```

I setup my master branch to track `cavneb/master`

```
$ git branch --set-upstream master cavneb/master
```

Every other branch tracks the corresponding branch from origin. Is there some way that I can see which remote branch is being tracked by each local branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what)

```
$ git branch -vv   # doubly verbose!
```

Comment: Is there some secret webpage that lists all these arcane Git commands that everyone except me seems to know?

Comment: `$ git branch --help` or the manpage.