# Git command equal to git push --prune

Tags: git

I looking for the command which not available in git version 1.7.4 but I am not be able to upgrade the git client.

So, are there any command which equivalent to

```
git push --prune
```

Answer (score 1):

- The `prune` for remote "Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `<name>`. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "`remotes/<name>`". "
- The `prune` for push "Remove remote branches that don’t have a local counterpart".

The idea would be to list all remote branches (`git branch -r`), and if there is no local branch with the same name, to `git push origin :remoteBranchName` (delete it on the remote)

Comment: when we prune, I needs to delete "all" remote branches which not available. To done manual with `git push origin :remoteBranchName` it still take time in case that we have 100+ branches and have to compare one-by-one.

Comment: @scalopus true, I was just giving the idea of what git push --prune does. To automate it, you would have to list all of the remote branches through a `git for-each-ref`, a bit like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4952368/6309