# How can I find out which of my local branches are tracking which remote branches?

Tags: git

When I do 'git branch', I get

```
* (no branch)
```

and when I do 'git remote', I get

```
test-mirror
test-dev
test-git
```

But I don't see how which of my local branch is tracking which remote branches?

I think it must have some mapping between my local branch with remote branch.
Otherwise, I don't get anything when I do 'git pull'.  But I have done 'git pull', I do see new changes.
How can I see the mapping between my local branch and remote branch?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you are not on any branch, so it can't be tracking anything;-) This is also called a detached head.

It means that you checked out a specific commit, rather than the tip of a branch, and as commits are immutable (fixed sha1) git won't be able to update it.

If it was at the tip of a branch you would get a new commit linked to the previous tip of the branch.

as 'nobody' commented/linked - use `git branch -vv   # doubly verbose!`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why when I do a 'repo sync' (a wrapper script from google for android project), why the value 'git branch -vv' changes? e.g. $ git branch -vv
* (no branch) 2653621

Comment: I've not used that, but google suggested http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html and a number of stack overflow comments.