# How can I color Git branches based on their names?

Tags: git, colors, git-branch

I have a number of branches in my local git repository and I keep a particular naming convention which helps me distinguish between recently used and old branches or between merged and not merged with master.

Is there a way to color branch names in the output of `git branch` according to some regexp-based rules without using external scripts?

The best I've come up with so far is to run `git branch` through an external script, and create an alias. However, this may not be very portable...

Comment: Looking at [git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984968/color-git-branches-based-on-their-names) doc. I dont think this is possible

Comment: Using a custom script is the way to go, but use `git for-each-ref` (plumbing) rather than `git branch` (porcelain).

Comment: `git for-each-ref` looks cool, I've never used it before.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18070271/2541573

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `git-branch` doesn't let you do that

> Is there a way to color branch names in the output of `git branch` according to some regexp-based rules without using external scripts?

No; Git doesn't offer you a way of customising the colors in the output of `git branch` based on patterns that the branch names match.

## Write a custom script

> The best I've come up with so far is to run `git branch` through an external script, and create an alias.

One approach is indeed to write a custom script. However, note that [`git branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) is a porcelain Git command, and, as such, it shouldn't be used in scripts. Prefer the plumbing Git command [`git-for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) for that.

Here is an example of such a script; customize it to suit your needs.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# git-colorbranch.sh

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    printf "usage: git colorbranch\n\n"
    exit 1
fi

# color definitions
color_master="\033[32m"
color_feature="\033[31m"
# ...
color_reset="\033[m"

# pattern definitions
pattern_feature="^feature-"
# ...

git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
    while read ref; do

        # if $ref the current branch, mark it with an asterisk
        if [ "$ref" = "$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)" ]; then
            printf "* "
        else
            printf "  "
        fi

        # master branch
        if [ "$ref" = "master" ]; then
            printf "$color_master$ref$color_reset\n"
        # feature branches
        elif printf "$ref" | grep --quiet "$pattern_feature"; then
            printf "$color_feature$ref$color_reset\n"
        # ... other cases ...
        else
            printf "$ref\n"
        fi

    done
```

## Make an alias out of it

Put the script on your path and run

```
git config --global alias.colorbranch '!sh git-colorbranch.sh'
```

## Test

Here is what I get in a toy repo (in GNU bash):

[image]