# Git isn't fetching upstream data?

Tags: git, github

I have Git setup to have access to two *github* repositories: the upstream  remote that I don't have collaborator (write) access to, and the fork I created of that which I do have write access to. Below is what I get when I run `git remote -v`.

```
origin  https://github.com/samholmes1337/secret-society (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/samholmes1337/secret-society (push)
upstream    https://github.com/asm-products/secret-society.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/asm-products/secret-society.git (push)
```

However when I try to run `git fetch upstream` in order to retrieve the latest changes and [have them stored in a new branch called upstream/master](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/), it pauses for a second and then nothing happens.

[image: empty output of 'git remote -v']

And when I check my branches to see whether anything has been fetched, I just see the `master` branch and nothing else, as though there have been no changes retrieved. What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you precise how you "check your branches"?

Comment: I run `git branch`, which just yields one result: `* master`.

Comment: would you please show the output of `cat .git/config`

Comment: I see, you need `-a` to show the remote branches, as per both answers you got so far.

Comment: Oh hang on so `git fetch upstream` _doesn't_ place them in a local directory? Or it does and there's just nothing new in the remote repository?

Comment: Your local directory reflects what is *checked out*. With `fetch` you fetch the commits you want, but the new data is only in your `.git/`. Your local files won't change until you run `checkout` on these commits. This is what I mean in my answer, `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` updates your local files with what you just fetched.

Comment: And putting the newly fetched commits in a local branch makes them easier to access, and to integrate if you want to keep them. It really sounds like you want to `pull`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should mean the remote tracking upstream branches are already up-to-date.

You can check that with:

```
git branch -avv
```

That will display *all* the branches, including the remote tracking one, with their associated SHA1.

As mentioned in the comments, even if the remote tracking branch are not up-to-date and were actually fetching new commits, that would not place anything in the working tree.

Only a merge of `upstream/master` would do so. Since `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`, doing a `git pull` might be more convenient.

Comment: What does the third `v` in `-avvv` do?

Comment: Just checked the remote repository and forced it out-of-sync, it now works correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @Gauthier same as the doubly verbose option, actually (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4952368/6309)

Comment: @VonC: I see no `vvv` in your link, only `vv`. Both do exactly the same thing on my machine (1.9.1), which is why I wondered about the *third* `v`. Another way to put it: what is the difference between `vv` and `vvv`.

Comment: @Gauthier my link was about the double verbose `-vv`. Any `v` you add after the first two are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` only fetches the commits, it does no merging, no updating of your references (which are not remote references).

See with `git branch -a` if you have branches called `remotes/upstream/*`.

You can also get what you just fetched with `git checkout FETCH_HEAD`.

If you want your local `master` to reflect `upstream`'s `master`, you need to `git checkout master && git pull upstream master`. This works if the history of `master` has not diverged (ie you have your local work in another branch). It fetches first, then merges the `FETCH_HEAD` to your local master, allowing you to see the new commits.

If you want to get a branch from `upstream` and create a local reference at the same time: `git fetch upstream master:upstream_master`.

Answer (score 1):

`git branch` show local branches by default

you need to add `-a-` or `--all` to list both remote-tracking and local branches.

I suggest you look at `git branch -h` to check the other options.