# Prevent git to push to wrong remote

Tags: git, github, push, git-remote

I have a local branch "gh" that I always want to push to my account on github; I also have another local branch "lab" that I always want to push to my organization's account on github.
I have setup two remotes (gh and lab) for that.

```
$ git remote -v
gh  git@Ninguem.github.com:Ninguem/prj.git (fetch)
gh  git@Ninguem.github.com:Ninguem/prj.git (push)
lab git@Ninguem.github.com:lab-rasparta-org/prj.git (fetch)
lab git@Ninguem.github.com:lab-rasparta-org/prj.git (push)
```

I'm afraid to inadvertently mess the two when pushing. Is there a way to prevent that?
**Note:**
I've already fetched the two successfully, so I thing they're somehow "linked" together correctly... how do I manage what branches are "linked" to what remote branches and is there a safety mechanism?

Comment: take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4950725/390819). I think they contain what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you might be confusing the terms *branch* and *remote*:

- A [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) Remote repositories are versions of your project that are hosted on the Internet or network somewhere.
- A [branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) let's you create an isolated environment for making changes in a repository.

---

I believe you're trying to avoid confusion between pushing to the wron remote.

So suppose you have a branch `my_branch` in your personal GitHub account.

The safer way to ensure the remote you're working with is to explicitly say what remote are you pushing to:

- If you want to push to your personal repository:

  ```
  git push gh my_branch
  ```
- If you want to push to your organization's repository:

  ```
  git push lab working_branch
  ```

It will be his pattern:

**`git push <remote> <remote_branch>`**

---

You could also set up a local branch to track the remote branch on your remote `gh` like this:

```
git checkout -b my_branch -t gh/my_branch
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just learned that -vv option to git-branch shows me what remote/branch each local branch is tracking. Also noted that **not** specifying the remote pushes to the correct one. maybe I should just stick to that rule (not a "safety mechanism" though).

Comment: I could not understand where I may have messed the terms. Not a native speaker, sorry. maybe the last sentence should be "[...]how do I manage what **local** branches are "linked" to what remote branches[...]".

Comment: `I have a local branch gh` and `I have a local branch lab` which were the same names as the remotes led me to think that. Do you have local branches with the same names as the remotes?

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid messing things out, then you could consider working with two local repos, each [cloning a specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4568323/6309):

- one cloning Ninguem.github.com:Ninguem/prj.git
- one cloning Ninguem.github.com:lab-rasparta-org/prj.git

That way, you are *sure* you are not in the wrong branch, or pushing to the wrong remote.

Comment: @Ninguém no because the local path of the repo would clearly mention repoA or repoB.

Comment: Once again. You are right, but just in the unlikely event that I was paying attention to those kinds of details. That's precisely what I'm afraid to miss. ;-)

Comment: @Ninguém tryingg to manage that in the same repo is more dangerous than in separate repo, in my experience.

Comment: Hum... Don't you think the automatic mechanism of branch tracking is safe eneugh, as long as I don't wrongly mention the wrong remote name in the push command?