# Git SourceTree has "forgotten" remote branch to pull when pulling local branch

Tags: git, sourcetree

I don't know how this has happened but in SourceTree when I do a pull for my develop branch from my remote (origin) SourceTree never seems to know what the "Remote branch to pull" is any more.  Instead every time I have to manually select develop.

[image]

Is there a way I can reassign my local develop branch back to my origin develop in Git or through SourceTree so I don't have to keep selecting the develop branch from the drop down list?

I'm using SourceTree 1.9.6.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you're not tracking the correct branch
Right click your develop branch and select

> Track remote branch

Then find origin/develop

This will now be the default branch when you pull.

Comment: Nice one! Didnt even know that option existed.  Is that a SourceTree thing or is the tracking stored in Git somewhere?

Comment: Happy it worked, it's a git thing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what