# What git command tells me if my local branch is derived from one on the remote server?

Tags: git

When I do

```
git branch -l
```

I see my local branches, but where can I see if it was just my own branch created locally or if it is a local branch created from remote? My understanding is there is a remote branch originally. Then I created my branch off that with

```
git branch NAME_OF_REMOTE_BRANCH
```

What if I do

```
git branch -b NAME_OF_REMOTE_BRANCH
```

What's the difference?

Comment: _Every_ Git branch is derived from something, except for `master`, but even that usually is cloned from a branch which exists on a remote server.

Comment: git branch --remotes will give you all remote branches

Comment: ok I think git branch -vv is kind of what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git show-branch -current -r
```

give your current branch history

```
 git branch -b not work on git,
error: unknown switch `b'
```

perhaps you mean `git checkout -b`?

in this case the command is used to create a new branch from the current one.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what) explains how you find out which branch is tracking which other branch, if any. If a branch is tracking any branch on `origin`, or whatever your remote is called, it was either directly checked out from it or the tracking branch was set manually. If you created a branch using `git branch NAME_OF_REMOTE_BRANCH` or `git checkout -b NAME_OF_REMOTE_BRANCH`, it is set to track `NAME_OF_REMOTE/NAME_OF_REMOTE_BRANCH`.