# what will "git push origin mybranch" do if it's in my mybrach now?

Tags: git

after commit, I meant to do git push which pushes into upstream, 
but did

```
git push origin mybranch
```

will it cause any change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, it will push your changes to whatever repository has been set as the remote called `origin`.

You can show what remotes you have, and where they point using

```
git remote -v
```

When you run `git push` on its own, it pushes to the default remote configured for your current branch. You can use [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what) to find out what that is. For instance, if:

```
git remote show upstream
```

Includes the line:

```
mybranch     pushes to mybranch
```

Then `git push` is equivalent to `git push upstream mybranch`.

More commonly, the default remote will be `origin` anyway, so `git push` and `git push origin mybranch` will do the same thing.