# VSCode doesn't recognize remote git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode 0.7.10 on Win10 with Git 1.9.5.msysgit.1. I can stage and check in to my local repo from vscode. The remote options are grayed out. However, I can see the remote repo in the bash and cmd via "git remote -v"

The output windows says something like:
git fetch
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

Could this be a path issue? Why can bash and cmd see/use the repo for a push but VSCode can not?

Comment: Does your local branch have an [upstream branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631706/what-is-this-branch-tracking-if-anything-in-git/16162827#16162827) configured?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thx.